# Count all values in object where X is the first key letter

Tags: javascript

I would like to count all values where a letter appears first and return the letter with atleast half of all values in my object so for example I assuming I have an object like this

```
const sample = { "A,B,C": 4, "B,C,A": 3, "C,B,A": 2, "A,C,B": 2 };
```

I would return A because if you count all the values where A appears first you would get 6 (4+2)

This is what I currently have:

```
for (let votes of Object.values(sample)) {
  sum += votes
}
stretchWin = Math.round(sum / 2)
winner = Object.entries(sample)
  .filter(([, val]) => val >= stretchWin)
  .map(([keys]) => keys)
```

With this I am getting an empty array because I am not counting all the values assigned to A

Comment: Where are you doing anything with the first letter of the key?

Comment: You need to create a new object whose keys are the first letters of the keys in the original object, and values are the total of all those values, e.g. `{'A': 6, 'B': 3, 'C': 2}`. Then you can filter this to find the ones with at least half the total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the whole sample first to get a sum of the values by the first letter first, *then* iterate over that new object to identify which values match the target of half the total.

```js
const sample = {
  "A,B,C": 4,
  "B,C,A": 3,
  "C,B,A": 2,
  "A,C,B": 2
};
const sumByChar = {};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(sample)) {
  const char = key[0];
  sumByChar[char] = (sumByChar[char] ?? 0) + value;
}
let sum = 0;
for (let votes of Object.values(sample)) {
  sum += votes
}
const targetSum = Math.round(sum / 2);
const winners = Object.entries(sumByChar)
  .filter(([, val]) => val >= targetSum)
  .map(([key]) => key);
console.log(winners);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you mean what the outcome should be. If I understand correctly you want something like this??

```js
const sample = { "A,B,C": 4, "B,C,A": 3, "C,B,A": 2, "A,C,B": 2 };
const totalSum = Object.values(sample).reduce(
  (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue,
  0
);
const stretchWin = Math.round(totalSum / 2);

const winner = Object.entries(sample)
  .filter(([key, value]) => {
    const isFirstLetterA = key.startsWith("A");
    return isFirstLetterA || value >= stretchWin;
  })
  .map(([key, value]) => value)
  .reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue, 0);

console.log(winner);
```